# Cant get my loop to work if there are more then one condition vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to right a macro that allows a user to input either 1, 2 or 3 and that come back with a message telling the user what number they picked. If the user puts in anything other then 1, 2 or 3 I want an error message to pop up, and then the user to be asked again to enter 1, 2 or 3. The problem I am having is that I can't get the loop to work if I put anything more then 1 condition in it. Here is my code

```
Public Sub ForecastReport()

    Dim sinput As Integer

    Do
        sinput = Application.InputBox("Please select 1 to 3 " & vbLf & vbLf & "1. GB IMCP" & vbLf & "2. IE IMCP" & vbLf & "3. US", "Enter a Value")

        Select Case sinput
        Case 1
            MsgBox ("you have selected GB IMCP")
        Case 2
            MsgBox ("you have selected IE IMCP")
        Case 3
            MsgBox ("you have selected US")
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("wrong input")
        End Select
    Loop Until sinput <> 3

End Sub
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity's sake I often just use a boolean toggle to handle when such a loop should be exited. This also handles the case where the inputbox returns a false, because the user has clicked cancel. Below you can see how I've done this for an inputbox where I want the value it returns to be a year between 2000 and 2050 (år = year). Usine InputBox type:=1 makes the inputbox only accept integers, which will be useful in your case as well.

```
  Dim år As Variant
  Dim gyldigVerdi As Boolean

  Do
    år = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Question", Title:="Title", Default:=Year(Date) + 1, Type:=1)
    If Not CBool(år) Then
      Exit Sub
    ElseIf CLng(år) < 2000 Or CLng(år) > 2050 Then
      MsgBox Prompt:="Error-message", Buttons:=vbExclamation, Title:="Title"
      gyldigVerdi = False
    Else
      gyldigVerdi = True
    End If
  Loop Until gyldigVerdi
```

Note that I use `Application.InputBox` instead of the generic VBA `InputBox` - for some of the differences between the two, you can have a look at [this page](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s2458/inputbox.htm).

If you're just interested in the comparison which will return true if the value is between one and three, have a look at the conditions for the first `ElseIf`, and use the opposite (x >= 1 And x <= 3).

Comment: Since the OP asked the question in English you may want to ensure your code is in English. Other users may have a difficult time understanding your code (particularly prompts and comments).

Comment: Keep in mind that SO isn't strictly meant for OP's, but instead for the many that may stumble upon our answers later on. OP *may* have been able to read your code (maybe not), but someone else who stumbles along may have left more confused than when they came in. For purposes of perpetuity, it is best to not assume what someone else will be able to understand, at least to the best of our ability. Also, your variables are still in another language. Since variables should ideally be descriptive, this is definitely something we want to be as clear as possible.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your help - much appreciated. Eirik, I am a little confused, what part of your code is dealing with is the user doesn't input anything. Sorry if its jumping out - I am very new to this.

Comment: I assumed that whatever gets put into the input-box is input by the user. Apart from that it is just handling the value you get from that input-box  - pretty similar to what you do in yours. If there is any particular part of the answer you'd like explained in more detail, I'd be happy to do it - please just clarify what is unclear. @MikeHill

Comment: Hi Eirik, Yeah that is correct, the user has to input. The part I am struggling with is how it checks for instance a mis match type, I have managed to get it working for anything that is outside the 1,2 or 3 and if no number is entered, but if I was to type "q" for instance it just comes back with a mis match error and stops, but I want it to just go back and ask to input the number again. Thank You

Comment: Well, as I mention just before the code-example, you can use InputBox Type:=1 to force it to only accept integers (you can also see how this is practically done in the code example). Then the only non-integer value you can get from the inputbox is `false`, if the user clicks cancel, and you can see how the first if-statement inside the do-loop checks for this, and exits the macro if the value from the inputbox is false (not false = true). @MikeHill

Comment: Thanks Eirik - I think maybe I just needed that explanation, because I couldn't see everything from the code example, due to my in-experience in this. But Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Loop Until sinput <= 3 And sinput > 0
```

It should be enough.

Comment: ok, that gave me an idea - so I have tried 

Loop Until sinput < 3

which seems to work now, unless the user puts in 0 or leaves it blank

Comment: What is wrong with `<> 3`? The user can put also a string like `test`.

Comment: <> 3 doesn't let 3 pass, I am trying to let 1, 2 and 3 pass and any other number have to be re-asked

Comment: @Vityata I think your code is meant to be `Loop Until sinput <= 3 And sinput > 0` since `3 < 3 = False`.

Comment: @BrandonBarney - yes, checked.